# How can I reformat ipynb code on Pycharm?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I know that "ctrl+alt+shift+L" is the 'reformat files' shortcut in Pycharm.

I can reformat .py code using the above shortcut, but I can not reformat .ipynb files.

When I open the reformat files tool and run it, it does not produce any changes.

How can I reformat ipynb code on Pycharm?

[image: reformat file window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem.

In fact, in PyCharm 2018.3.6, the code reformat function worked in ipynb files.
But in PyCharm 2019.3.3, the UI of jupyter notebook changed. And the code reformat function could not work.

Now I have to use the jupyter note book extension in browser to reformat my code.

It seems like a bug of PyCharm. Other person have met this problem.
https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebooks-in-the-ide-visual-studio-code-versus-pycharm-5e72218eb3e8